# Setting Linux environment variable for another user (sudo)

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables, sudo

How can we set environment variables for another user on a machine? I want to run some script with `sudo -u xyz` but I need to set some environment variables before running the script for xyz user which is different from my login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `env(1)` man page:

> ```
> NAME
>        env - run a program in a modified environment
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        env [OPTION]... [-] [NAME=VALUE]... [COMMAND [ARG]...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        Set each NAME to VALUE in the environment and run COMMAND.
> ```

Comment: can you elaborate on your answer?

Answer (score 35):

You can add VAR=VALUE between the `sudo -u xyz` and the script. Example

```
sudo -u xyz LANG=C LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib some_script.sh
```